# Manjaro login screen not displaying locale selector

Tags: login-screen, manjaro, locale

Manjaro has a bar at the bottom of the login screen (came with XFCE install) that displays a lot of accessibility options, such as high contrast and large text. Until recently, it also displayed a language selector that said `en_US.utf8` or something like that. I didn't have any other languages on the system. Today, I installed a different language from the locale settings in the graphical settings manager. Now it says `[language_code]` and doesn't have a selector.
I'm not very fluent in the other language and I kind of need both for different things. I really want to use the login language switcher so I'm not stuck trying to do something in a different language to reconfigure settings.

Answer (score 0):

Used help from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604134/how-to-fix-missing-locale-files-on-manjaro) unix stackexchange question. All I did was reinstall `glibc`, and it fixed itself.